# webpack / Production shortcut -p: migrate CLI to Node.js API

Tags: webpack

We're planning to move the webpack build approach from CLI to Node.js API.

This means, moving from: 1st apprach

> webpack -p --config /path/to/config/file

to: 2nd approach

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var config = require('/path/to/same/config/file/as/above');

// returns a Compiler instance
webpack(config, function(err, stats) {
    // ...
});
```

The question is: How do we pass the -p option of CLI approach here in the 2nd approach (node.js API)?

Note: the -p option of CLI is to make the build optimized for production.  We need the same optimization (whatever it is) in our 2nd approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `webpack --help`, `-p` is a shortcut for `--optimize-minimize --define process.env.NODE_ENV="production"`. According to [the source code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/blob/b3186a9/bin/convert-argv.js#L484-L501), `--optimize-minimize` applies the `UglifyJsPlugin` and `LoaderOptionsPlugin` with some options, and `--define` applies the [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/). So you might want to do this:

```
plugins: [
    // ...
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
        // sourceMap: true (if needed)
    }),
    new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: true
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    })
]
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to add these plugins in the config to get the effect of having the -p option?

Comment: Exactly, I updated my answer accordingly to make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot simon04